# Update parent React component from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-context

I'm using react context api to show my data everywhere and updating from everywhere I want that my data can be show on multiple screens and I can update from more than one class I need to use that globally.

When I try to update it from class profile screens nothing happen but it can be updating from class home screen.

How Can I show my data in consumer without using  like this ,and show this data globally

```
const Context = React.createContext("default value")    
global.cart = 1;
```

Class home screen that is context provider class

```
class HomeScreen extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
          contextData:5}}
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <Context.Provider value={this.state.contextData}>
        <Button title="Increment" onPress={++global.cart;
        this.setState({contextData:global.cart})}/>
      </Context.Provider>
      <ProfileScreens/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

text that I need to use and show in many screens

```
class ProfileScreen extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
  return (
      <View style={{}}>
        <Context.Consumer>
          {data=>  <Text style={{fontSize:50}}>{data.toString()}</Text>}
        </Context.Consumer>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

another class which is changing the context provider  data

```
class ProfileScreens extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={contextData:5}}
  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Context.Provider value={this.state.contextData}>
          <ProfileScreen/>
          <Button title="decrementss" onPress={()=>{  ++global.cart;
            this.setState({contextData:global.cart})}}/>
        </Context.Provider>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass a callback down from `HomeScreen` to `ProfileScreens` 
this callback would be called within `ProfileScreens` and trigger `HomeScreen` state change:

in `HomeScreen`:

```
...
<ProfileScreens changeHomeScreen={() => this.setState({...})}/>
...
```

then in `ProfileScreens`:

```
...
<Button title="decrementss" onPress={()=>{ this.props.changeHomeScreen() }}/>
...
```

Comment: How Can I show my data in consumer without using like this ,and show this data globally